# How to simplify the following PDE by changing the variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking forward to solving the following 1 D convection-advection equation by using the changing of variables.

$$ 4r \frac{∂^2T}{∂r^2} - 2γ \frac{∂T}{∂r}= θ \frac{∂T}{∂t}$$

I have tried to solve the equation by changing the variables as follow:

$$ T(r,t) = U(r,t) exp(C_1 r + C_2 t)$$

and find the values of $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that the PDE is simplified but I found this technique fails due to $r$ in the second derivative term. Can this equation be simplified by this technique?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that $\gamma$ and $\theta$ are constants.)

Instead of changing the dependent variable $T\mapsto U$, change the independent variable $r\mapsto x$. (I'll use subscripts for partial derivatives.) The chain rule says

$$T_r = T_x x_r$$

$$T_{rr} = (T_x)_r x_r + T_x x_{rr}$$

$$= \big((T_x)_x x_r\big)x_r + T_x x_{rr}$$

$$= T_{xx} x_r\!^2 + T_x x_{rr}$$

so your equation becomes

$$4r\big(T_{xx} x_r\!^2 + T_x x_{rr}\big) - 2\gamma\big(T_x x_r\big) = \theta T_t$$

$$= \big(4rx_r\!^2\big)T_{xx} + \big(4rx_{rr} - 2\gamma x_r\big)T_x$$

To simplify this, we want the first derivative to disappear, so

$$4rx_{rr} - 2\gamma x_r = 0$$

$$\frac{1}{x_r}x_{rr} = \frac{\gamma}{2r}$$

integrating with respect to $r$

$$\ln|x_r| = \frac\gamma2\ln|r| + C_1$$

$$x_r = C_2 r^{\gamma/2}$$

integrating again

$$x = \frac{C_2}{\gamma/2+1} r^{\gamma/2+1} + C_3$$

(In the special case $\gamma = -2$, this would instead be a logarithm: $x = C_2\ln|r| + C_3$.)

We can choose $C_3 = 0$ to simplify:

$$x = \frac{C_2}{\gamma/2+1}r^{\gamma/2+1}$$

$$r = \Bigg(\frac{\gamma/2+1}{C_2}x\Bigg)^{1/(\gamma/2+1)}$$

Now the original equation becomes

$$\big(4rx_r\!^2\big)T_{xx} = \theta T_t$$

$$= 4r\big(C_2\!^2r^\gamma\big)T_{xx}$$

$$= 4C_2\!^2r^{\gamma+1}T_{xx}$$

$$= 4C_2\!^2\Bigg(\frac{\gamma/2+1}{C_2}x\Bigg)^{(\gamma+1)/(\gamma/2+1)}T_{xx}$$

$$= \theta C_4x^{(\gamma+1)/(\gamma/2+1)}T_{xx}$$

(I choose the factor of $\theta$ for this new constant $C_4$ to cancel it from the other side of the equation:)

$$C_4x^{(\gamma+1)/(\gamma/2+1)}T_{xx} = T_t$$

Is this the kind of simplification you were looking for?

Comment: It seems to be simple compared with the original form. Thanks very much.